# How can I store some columns on a list using the function dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dataframe

```
data_dict = {'A': 'foo',
         'B': 'age',
         'C': [10, 20, 30,],
         'D': 3.14}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict, index=[10, 20, 30])
```

I have this dataframe and I want to return in a list the columns where the values are object. I know that I have to use the function dtype to do this but I don't know how to write it correctly.

This is what I wrote:

```
df1=df.columns[np.where(df.dtype='objects')].to_list()
df1
```

But this doesn't work I got **SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression**

Comment: just `df.columns[df.dtypes.eq("object")].to_list()` ? no need for np.where here

Comment: df.select_dtypes(include='object')